# Python tkinter Attribute Error: class has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have read all similar questions asked but I still can't figure out how to solve the error. I am creating a countdown timer that will update and show the remaining time on the 'timeLeft' label(code below). However, I keep getting this error when I try to update the label with function start_count() :

```
self.timeLeft.config(text= str(mins) +"分"+ str(secs) +"秒")
AttributeError: 'PracticePage' object has no attribute 'timeLeft'
```

Below is part of my code:

```
    class PracticePage(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            timeLeft = tk.Label(self,text= "")
            backButton = ttk.Button(self, text="やり直す", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
            homeButton = ttk.Button(self, text="サインアウト", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(SignInPage))

            timeLeft.pack()
            backButton.pack()
            homeButton.pack()
            self.start_count(120)

        def start_count(self,t):
            global mins
            global secs
            time = t
            while time>0:
                mins, secs = divmod(time,60)
                mins = round(mins)
                secs = round(secs)
                self.timeLeft.config(text= str(mins) +"分"+ str(secs) +"秒")
                time = time-1
                if (time==0):
                   break
```

Can someone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure that anywhere you have `timeLeft` to change it to `self.timeLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

You seam to misunderstand how a class attribute works or what exactly `self.` is doing.

The `self.` prefix is used to tell the class that a specific variable or function is being assigned as a class attribute or method.

Here you have created a variable in the `__init__` method called `timeLeft` however you try to access it later with `self.timeLeft`. This will not work as `timeLeft` was defined as a local variable only to the `__init__` method.

To correct this simply make sure `timeLeft` is updated to be `self.timeLeft` anywhere in your code and it should work fine from there.

Updated class:

```
class PracticePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timeLeft = tk.Label(self,text= "")
        backButton = ttk.Button(self, text="やり直す", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        homeButton = ttk.Button(self, text="サインアウト", command = lambda:controller.show_frame(SignInPage))

        self.timeLeft.pack()
        backButton.pack()
        homeButton.pack()
        self.start_count(120)

    def start_count(self,t):
        global mins
        global secs
        time = t
        while time>0:
            mins, secs = divmod(time,60)
            mins = round(mins)
            secs = round(secs)
            self.timeLeft.config(text= str(mins) +"分"+ str(secs) +"秒")
            time = time-1
            if (time==0):
               break
```